# select date is not showing at edit time in ng2-daterangepicker

Tags: angular, daterangepicker

I'm using `ng2-daterangepicker` https://github.com/evansmwendwa/ng2-daterangepicker for dates.

```
public singlePicker = {
        singleDatePicker: true,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        autoApply: true,
        drops: 'down',
        locale: {
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
        }
}

<input class="form-control form-line" type="text" daterangepicker 
id="dob" [options]="singlePicker" 
[(ngModel)]="dob" name="dob" />
```

storing date in db as `YYYY-MM-DD` and at edit time formatting with moment with

```
this.dob= moment(this.dob).format(DD MMM YYYY);
```

It shows the correct date in the placeholder with above format but when I click on datepicker it shows current date as selected in datepicker. it should show date from db which is showing in placeholder.

Comment: I think that `ng2-daterangepicker` expects two dates to pass, so probably ngModel data is wrong...

Comment: @NikolaSpalevic I have added `singleDatePicker: true`. then also it expects 2 date?

Comment: ok, I've haven't seen that... :) Please reference library when you ask questions like this...

Comment: @NikolaSpalevic updated in question

Comment: I've tried plunker so bug exists obviously... Open issue on github repo or change package if you have that option. My suggestion is flatpickr :)

Comment: @NikolaSpalevic it works well as expected?

Answer (score 1):

got the answer after digging for a while,

for showing date selected in datepicker, have to set `startDate` in `singlePicker` object.

so, it will be.

```
public singlePicker = {
        singleDatePicker: true,
        autoUpdateInput: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        autoApply: true,
        drops: 'down',
        locale: {
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
        }

}
```

and you can add value from the db to `startDate` like
`this.singlePicker['startDate] = this.dob`